# ¿ Podemos eliminar la palabra "productos" de nuestra URL en un sitio WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-api

quiero crear una tienda y haciendo pruebas, veo que desde desde el panel de administrador en `Ajustes >>> Enlaces Permanentes` , podemos personalizar la estructura de nuestras URLs .

Para los productos de la tienda, yo quiero eliminar de la URL la palabra `" /productos/"`, pero es imposible hasta ahora.

Me gustaría que la URL fuese de la siguiente manera:

**htpps://mitienda.com/nombreDelProducto**

Ejemplo:

Ahora la URL se muestra asi:

```
 httpsss://lenceria.org/producto/sujetador-selene-amanda
```

Y ejemplo de como quiero que se muestre la URL:

`https://lenceria.org/sujetador-selene-amanda`

Pero siempre sale **`https://mitienda/producto/nombreDelProducto`**

He probado cambiando en la sección de **`"Enlaces permanentes del producto"  >>>> Base Personalizada`** .

Elimino `" producto/"` , pero cuando guardo, aparece de nuevo la palabra `"producto/"`

¿ Existe la forma para eliminar esta palabra de mi URL ?
¿ Pueden ayudarme con esto ?

Comment: Creo que hay una contradicción en lo que necesitas y en lo que se muestra, por favor haz clic en [edit] tu pregunta y deja en claro: Qué tienes y qué quieres lograr.

Comment: corregido el error

Comment: Supongo que `producto` es la categoría o algo así ¿? Lo que quieres  se lograría eligiendo la opción **`Nombre de la entrada`** en ***Enlaces permanentes*.** Verifica que no incluiste `producto` en el slug, al crear el post, si es así, lo mejor es quitarlo manualmente.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano , no existe `producto`en esta parte de la configuración. Si lees mi pregunta, veras que en la parte de `Enlaces Permanentes del Producto`,  lo cambiado pero al guardar, vuelve al esta anterior

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario. No verás nunca la palabra `producto` en *Enlaces permanentes*, ahí se muestran patrones simplemente y si tú eliges la opción **`Nombre de la entrada`** y le das a guardar, verás solamente la parte de la URL, sin categorías ni nada. Lo que quiero saber es si `producto` es una categoría que has asignado a ese post, o si es algo que forma parte del slug o URL que pusiste al crear el post.

Comment: eso sucede porque seguramente estas usando woocomerce y los productos funcionan como un post type, no como paginas o post, hacer lo que pides es posible pero solo desde backend, no es lago que puedas hacer en fronted y puede causar problemas con paginas y post con nombres parecidos.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano , tu comentario me fue de gran ayuda

Comment: ¿Realmente necesitas quitarlo? Ese tipo de segmentación es muy útil al momento de rastrear y segmentar contenido en Google Analytics. De esa forma podrás diferenciar fácilmente las urls de producto, del resto de urls de tu sitio.

Comment: Creo que viendo los comentarios, olvidare eliminar esto @GabrielOrtiz , he leido más información y no es muy bueno hacer lo que yo quiero. Por ello, lo dejare tal y como esta. No se si deberia eliminar la pregunta o constarla yo dando una explicación de mim razonamiento. Gracias